# string consists of punctuation

Tags: python, regex, punctuation

I want to check if string contains punctuation or not so a continuous sequence of exclamation, question & both.
By continuous, it means more than 2 times. Just like below,

```
  #If sentence contains !!!
  exc = re.compile(r"(.)\!{2}")
  word["cont_exclamation"] = if exc.search(sent[i]) else not(found)

  #If sentence contains ???
  reg = re.compile(r"(.)\?{2}")
  word["cont_question"] = if reg.search(sent[i]) else not(found)
```

But now I want to find both, exclamation and question marks so for example, hello??! or hey!! or dude!?!

Also, what if I want ? and ! both but more than 2 any of them.

I dont know regex properly so any help would be great.

Answer (score 3):

Use the regex '[?!]{3,}' which means match the ? or ! characters 3 or more times (if continous = more than two times). Quoting is not needed inside character class.

Add more punctuation characters to the char class as needed

Comment: What if I want both ? and ! then?

Comment: That will work fine () is a character class which means either character will be matched.

Comment: Wouldn't the first answer given also unintentionally match any character (.) followed by only 2 ? or ! punctuation characters which isn't the spec? For example I believe it would actually match Hello!! when you only want it to match Hello!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
regex = re.compile(r"(.)(\?|\!){2}")
```

edit: Typing "regex tutorial" into google gives more info than you possibly need. [This tutorial](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm) looks particularly well-balanced between conciseness and completeness.

Particularly (i.m.o.) useful tricks that are often not mentioned:

- use `+?` and `*?` to switch from greedy to lazy match. I.e. match as few characters as possible instead of as much as possible. Example text: `#ab# #de#` --> `#.*?#` matches `#ab#` only (not `#ab# #de#`)
- parentheses create a capture group by default. If you don't want this, you can use `(?:`...`)`.

Most importantly, comment each regexp with a human-readable explanation. Future-you will be grateful. :-)

Comment: that worked like a charm. how would I improvise on regex.. any help?

Answer (score 2):

try `re.compile(r"(.)[\?\!]{2}")`

Comment: The ``\`` escapes are redundant here.

Comment: What if I want both ? and ! then?